# Sticky header disappears when cursor goes out of focus

Tags: html, css

I want to make the table header row sticky using CSS only. The following css gives the desired results, when scrolling the table rows, the header row sticks at top. However as soon the cursor is out of focus, the sticky row disappears and it appears again as I continue to scroll.

```css
table {
  border:1px solid black;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  width: 600px
}

th {
  border:1px solid green;
  padding: 6px 10px;
  background: green;
  color: #FFF
}

td {
  border-bottom: 1px solid green;
  border-left: 1px solid green;
  padding: 6px 10px;
}

tr.sticky {
    z-index: 99;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="sticky">
  <th>Th1</th>
  <th>Th2</th>
  <th>Th3</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>td1</td>
    <td>td2</td>
    <td>td3</td>
</tr>

<table>
```

Is there a way to keep it sticky even when the cursor is out of focus, or when stopped scrolling?

Edit: Sorry if my question was not clear. To replicate the issue, go here (https://jsfiddle.net/L0wvajqy/) and scroll the table half way through so you can see the row being sticky. Then take cursor somewhere on the page outside the table and you will notice that sticky row disappears. If it doesn't disappear, click somewhere outside the table and it will disappear.

The issue seems to be only in Firefox.

Comment: Please add more details. How do you focus any of those elements in the first place? They are not interactive elements. I also do not understand the issue you describe. The header remains sticky for me all the time.

Comment: @tacoshy Same for me.

Comment: @tacoshy I added more information to the question, please see.

Comment: No repro. What browser/OS?

Comment: proberly just a bug within jsfiddle.